# Yii2 получить id не связанных записей

Tags: php, yii2

Хочу получить все IDs не связанных записей.
Например у меня есть 3 таблицы:

1. пользователи
2. модули
3. модули_пользователя

И есть раздел Каталог, в котором можно подключить нужный модуль.
В каталоге есть 2 блока:

1. Сейчас подключено
2. Доступные модули

По началу все модули находятся в блоке **Доступные модули**, как только пользователь подключил его, он должен скрыться из этого блока и перейти в блок **Сейчас подключено**.

Мне нужно сделать это средствами  Yii2 ORM. Если написать чистый SQL, то получится так

```
SELECT m.id FROM 
`modules` as m
inner join `user_modules` as um on um.id_module = m.id
inner join `users` as us on um.id_user = us.id
```

Comment: https://yiiframework.com.ua/ru/doc/guide/2/db-query-builder/#join

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы получить подключенные модули пользователя, можно создать реляцию с использованием промежуточной таблицы.

```
public function getModulesEnable()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Modules::class, ['id' => 'id_user'])
        ->viaTable('user_modules', ['id_module' => 'id']);
}
```

Чтобы получить отключенные модули, используем обычный запрос, но исключаем подключенные модули. Для этого получаем айдишники подключенных модулей и сохраняем их в свойстве `$this->enableModulesIds`. Либо передаем параметром, чтобы было более очевидно.

```
public function getModulesDisable(){
    return Modules::find()->where(['!=', 'id', $this->enableModulesIds])->all();
}
```

Comment: Вот это хороший ответ! Спасибо